# Cannot use overextends in Wagtail admin

Tags: django, wagtail

I try to replace default logo and title in a Wagtail app. According to http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.0b1/howto/custom_branding.html I've created `templates/wagtailadmin/`, have installed `django-overextends` and added `overextends` to my project’s INSTALLED_APPS object(`base.py`).

As a result is error `Invalid block tag on line 1: 'overextends'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?`

How can I correctly load `overextends` module to make it work? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [overextends readme](https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-overextends#project-configuration)

In Django 1.9+, you must add overextends to the builtins key of your TEMPLATES setting

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'builtins': ['overextends.templatetags.overextends_tags'],
        }
    },
]
```

For most extensions which feature template tags, you need to load them in each template, e.g. `{% load overextends_tags %}`, but overextends is different, and in earlier versions of Django it self-adds to the builtins, see https://github.com/stephenmcd/django-overextends/blob/master/overextends/models.py

Note, Wagtail 1.0 is an old version, and the latest is 1.5.2. The [Wagtail 1.5.2 Custom Branding documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.5.2/advanced_topics/customisation/branding.html?highlight=branding) does detail the above template configuration step.

Update October 2016: Wagtail is now well past version 1.5. See @gasman's comment below for more.

Comment: Thanks, man. Now it works. They missed this important tip in a wagtail docs.

Comment: Not quite. The Wagtail docs you linked to were for 1.0b1, and that predated Django 1.9. In the then latest contemporary version of Django, this tip wasn't necessary. As I wrote above, the latest Wagtail docs (1.5.2) do contain this step.

Comment: In Django 1.9, the `overextends` package is not needed at all, as Django now provides the same functionality natively. This is reflected in the master version of the docs (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/advanced_topics/customisation/branding.html), but this hasn't made it into a release version of the documentation yet.